# Xcode 8 Automatic Provisioning vs Manual

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning

In my project I have four main configurations:  Debug, Release, AdHoc, AppStore.  Prior to Xcode 8 I had to create provisioning profiles for each of my targets, for each of these configurations and schemes.

I seemed to have some trouble when Xcode 8 Beta 1 released.  So I switched to the new "Automatic Provisioning".  Surprisingly it worked, I was even able to upload to Fabric/Crashlytics.  but I noticed my Push notifications are going to the wrong APNS environment.  Today I realized that my AdHoc configuation is really getting signed as "Development".  So those builds are registering with the SANDBOX APNS instead.  which is why my Pushes weren't working.

Today I switched back to Manual and specified all profiles on each target.  It seems to work fine.  Is "Manual" the only way to use AdHoc?

Do I even need to use AdHoc anymore?  My "Development" builds install fine for other people on on Crashlytics.